# Как использовать файловую систему смартфонов из мобильного приложения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-development, cordova, jquery-mobile

Делаю приложение с помощью jquery + jquery mobile, приложение берет некий файл с данными через Ajax с сервера, обрабатывает. Встал вопрос - нужна работа приложения при отсутствие интернета. Я так понимаю, мне при первой загрузке надо этот файл переместить на флэш смартфона, а далее работать уже с ним. При доступе к интернету приложение проверяет изменился ли файл на сервере и если что, обновляет его на флэшпамяти телефона. С ходу не смог найти ничего, в каком хоть направление двигаться? Само приложение упаковывается с помощью Cordova.

Comment: Так как на вопрос никто не ответил, отвечу сам, плюнул на файловую систему и применил localStorage, данные все равно не больше 5М, поэтому работает нормально